# How the VoidCallback in Flutter works?

Tags: flutter

> What I have understood from the sources on the internet is that ***VoidCallback()*** is function which takes no parameters and returns no parameters.
> The following code is from an application and the application is working perfectly, I want to ask that what are the reasons to use VoidCallback as a **type** and not as a **function** ?
>
> I am an absolute beginner in Flutter Development, please guide me.

```
class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final BaseAuth auth;
  final VoidCallback onSignedIn;
  LoginPage(this.auth);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    // TODO: implement createState
    return (_LoginPageState());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

VoidCallback IS void Function:

```
typedef VoidCallback = void Function();
```

> VoidCallback is function which takes no parameters and returns no parameters
>
> **Function** is base class for all function types.

So technically you could do

```
//instead of
final VoidCallback onSignedIn;
// could call this
final Function onSignedIn;
```

But if you want to pass Specific functions. Let's say function that don't take any params or return anything, VoidCallback would be better choices as it checks the type.

```
class A {
  final Function function;
  A(this.function){
    function("test"); // gonna print test
  }
}

class B {
  final VoidCallback voidCallback;
  B(this.voidCallback){
    voidCallback(); // gonna run void function
  }
}

String getString(String value) {
  print(value);
  return value;
}

void main() {
  A(getString);
  B(getString); //The argument type 'String Function(String)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function()'
}
```

You can also set up your own function definitions with [typedef](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#typedefs)

Comment: Why we are using this VoiceCallback function as a type?

Comment: We are passing VoidCallback function reference to another function. Most of the time to run it @Hasnain gonna update my answer

Comment: Thank You ! @Nuts                                                                                                                   Can you also tell me that when one should use VoidCallback ? any rule of thumb ?

Comment: When if you have a void function without params and you want to pass it somewhere always use voidCallback

Answer (score 2):

Typedefs are used to avoid losing type informations, but VoidCallback doesn't really have anything to lose, but you only know that because it's a VoidCallback. If it was just a `Function` you could end up trying to get a value from it. It's a utility for us and compiler.

Typedefs provide useful information for both tools and developers.

You can checkout [the language tour](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#typedefs) for more informations.

Comment: Why we are using this VoiceCallback function as a type?

Comment: Because `Function` is too broad. You could say that VoidCallback is like a documentation, but on the typing level.