# How to pass function onChanged with dynamic variable from reusable widget to other screen in flutter?

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart

I need to pass the function onChanged of StringInputTextBox into the textbox on the login page. However, it shows the error
`"The argument type 'void Function(dynamic)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function()?'."` in the login.dart. The main aim is to print the input of the email and password textbox in the debug console. I don't know how to declare the function of StringInputTextBox with a dynamic variable. Your help is much appreciated.

`login.dart`

```
class Login extends StatefulWidget {
  const Login({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _LoginState createState() => _LoginState();
}

class _LoginState extends State<Login> {

  //text field state
  String email = '';
  String password = '';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        FocusScopeNode currentFocus = FocusScope.of(context);

        if (!currentFocus.hasPrimaryFocus) {
          currentFocus.unfocus();
        }
      },
      child: Scaffold(
          body: SafeArea(
              child: Center(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(children: [
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 20, 0, 20),
              child: Image.asset(
                'assets/images/app_logo_large.png',
                height: 200,
                width: 200,
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 20),
              child: Column(
                children: const [
                  Text('Welcome To', style: landingLabelStyle),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 10,
                  ),
                  Text('JustShop', style: landingLabelStyle),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            StringInputTextBox(
                inputLabelText: 'Username',
                onChanged: (val) {
                  setState(() => email = val);
                }),
            StringInputTextBox(
              inputLabelText: 'Password',
              onChanged: (val) {
                setState(() => password = val);
              },
            ),
            Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(30, 0, 30, 0),
                child: Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end, children: [
                  LinkButton(
                    buttonText: 'Forgot your password?',
                    onClick: () {
                      Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/forgetpassword');
                    },
                  ),
                ])),
            const SizedBox(height: 20),
            BlackTextButton(
              buttonText: 'LOG IN',
              onClick: () async {
                print(email);
                print(password);
              },
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(30, 0, 30, 0),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: [
                  const Text('Need a JustShop Account?'),
                  LinkButton(
                    buttonText: 'Sign up here',
                    onClick: () {
                      Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/signup');
                    },
                  )
                ],
              ),
            )
          ]),
        ),
      ))),
    );
  }
}
```

`input_text_box.dart`

```
class StringInputTextBox extends StatefulWidget {
  final String inputLabelText;
  final VoidCallback? onChanged;

  const StringInputTextBox(
      {Key? key, required this.inputLabelText, required this.onChanged})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  _StringInputTextBoxState createState() => _StringInputTextBoxState();
}

class _StringInputTextBoxState extends State<StringInputTextBox> {
  final formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Form(
      key: formKey,
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(35, 10, 35, 0),
        child: TextFormField(
          cursorHeight: 18,
          cursorColor: Colors.black,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            labelText: widget.inputLabelText,
            floatingLabelStyle: const TextStyle(
              fontSize: 20,
              color: secondaryColor,
            ),
            contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 0, 20, 0),
            floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.auto,
            enabledBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.zero,
            ),
            focusedBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.zero,
            ),
          ),
          style: primaryFontStyle,
        ),
      ),
      onChanged: () => widget.onChanged,
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like this

1. create a TextEditingController instance to control the value in the input
2. Link the controller to the TextFormField
3. Pass the value of the controller to the callback using _inputController.text

**input_text_box.dart**

```
class StringInputTextBox extends StatefulWidget {
  final String inputLabelText;
  final VoidCallback? onChanged;

  const StringInputTextBox(
      {Key? key, required this.inputLabelText, required this.onChanged})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  _StringInputTextBoxState createState() => _StringInputTextBoxState();
}

class _StringInputTextBoxState extends State<StringInputTextBox> {
  final formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  
  // 1. Create a TextEditingController instance
  final TextEditingController _inputController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Form(
      key: formKey,
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(35, 10, 35, 0),
        child: TextFormField(
          // 2. link TextEditingController instance with the input
          controller: _inputController,
          cursorHeight: 18,
          cursorColor: Colors.black,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            labelText: widget.inputLabelText,
            floatingLabelStyle: const TextStyle(
              fontSize: 20,
              color: secondaryColor,
            ),
            contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 0, 20, 0),
            floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.auto,
            enabledBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.zero,
            ),
            focusedBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.zero,
            ),
          ),
          style: primaryFontStyle,
        ),
      ),
      // 3. Pass your value to the callback
      onChanged: () => widget.onChanged(_inputController.text),
    );
  }
}
```

And now you can get val in your **login.dart**

```
StringInputTextBox(
  inputLabelText: 'Username',
  // 4. This is the value of the controller
  onChanged: (String val) {
    setState(() => email = val);
  }),
```

Let me know if you need more help.

Comment: Hi, I get the error "Too many positional arguments: 0 expected, but 1 found.
Try removing the extra arguments." at the line onChanged: () => widget.onChanged!(_inputController.text) in input_text_box.dart.

Comment: In the input_text_box.dart file change `final VoidCallback? onChanged;`with `final Function? onChanged;`. The VoidCallback is a function which takes no parameters and returns no parameters. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59195034/how-the-voidcallback-in-flutter-works) for more details

Answer (score 0):

Change your code as follows

```
class StringInputTextBox extends StatefulWidget {
      final String inputLabelText;
      final ValueChanged<String>? onChanged;
    
      const StringInputTextBox(
          {Key? key, required this.inputLabelText, required this.onChanged})
          : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      _StringInputTextBoxState createState() => _StringInputTextBoxState();
    }
    
    class _StringInputTextBoxState extends State<StringInputTextBox> {
      final formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Form(
          key: formKey,
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(35, 10, 35, 0),
            child: TextFormField(
              cursorHeight: 18,
              cursorColor: Colors.black,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                labelText: widget.inputLabelText,
                floatingLabelStyle: const TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 20,
                  color: secondaryColor,
                ),
                contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 0, 20, 0),
                floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.auto,
                enabledBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.zero,
                ),
                focusedBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.zero,
                ),
              ),
              style: primaryFontStyle,
            ),
          ),
          onChanged: widget.onChanged,
        );
      }
    }
```

And now you can get val in your login.dart

```
StringInputTextBox(
  inputLabelText: 'Username',
  // 4. This is the value of the controller
  onChanged: (String val) {
    setState(() => email = val);
  }),
```